Laravel belongsToMany on a pivot table
is it possible for a pivot table to have a many-to-many relation of it's own; an example:
exams_table
parts_table
exam_part_pivot_table
teachers_table
exam_part_teacher_pivot_table
class Exam extends Model
{
    public function parts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Part::class);
    }
}
class Part extends Model
{
    public function exams() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Exam::class);
    }
}
class ExamPart extends Pivot
{
    public function teachers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
    }
}
class Teacher extends Model
{
    public function examParts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ExamPart::class);
    }
}

I'm aware that this is possible with multiple one-to-many relations by making exam_part_pivot a Model instead of a Pivot. i'm wondering if many-to-many-to-many is possible with laravel's eloquent or any other package.

I know that ternary relationships are not supported in Laravel and this is taking ternary relationships to the next level so I will go ahead and speculate that Laravel does not support this use case either (to be honest I think you should revise your data model because this design looks like it's trying to do too much)
